# Add time to Sale Date Price on Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, jquery-ui-datepicker

Does anyone know how to format time on **Sale Date Price** in **Woocommerce**.

Default datepicker format of **Sale date price** on is:

`YYYY-MM-DD`.

However I want it to be:

`YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s`

Thank you very much!